# How do I use parameters + dependency injection in a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

Here is what I want to do

```
    (function(){angular.module('app').factory("loadDataForStep",ls);
        ls.$inject = ['$scope','stepIndex']
        function ls ($scope, stepIndex) {
            if ($routeParams.code != undefined) {
                $scope.code = $routeParams.code;
                $scope.retrieveData($routeParams.code);
            }
            $rootScope.stepIndex = stepIndex-1;
            $rootScope.currentStep = stepIndex;
            $rootScope.resultsLoaded = false;
            if (!fieldDefinitionsLoaded) {
                loadAllElementsDefinition();
                loadStepsWithOverrides(stepIndex, loadStep);
            } else {
                loadStep(stepIndex);
            }
    }
    })();
```

I know there are plenty of issues here, but the issue of the moment (the question) is **How do I get $scope injected and pass step index as a parameter?** As you can see, $scope needs to come from angular, but I need to provide stepIndex.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Service don't have scope So can't inject scope in factory.

Scope is an instance of controller.

If you wanna to deal scope object in factory then declare variable in factory then bind factory with scope variable.

Then try kinda like this

```
var app = angular.module("app",[]);
app.factory("mySvc",function(){

  return {
    dataList : []
  }

});

app.controller("myCtrl",function($scope,mySvc){
   $scope.model=mySvc;
   console.log($scope.model);
});
```